# Is it possible to load data from the server using a HTTP POST request within a Magento Module js file?

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, custom, post

Is it possible to load data from the server using an HTTP POST request within a Magento Module js file?

File located in
app/code/MyVendor/myCustomModule/view/frontend/web/js/mycustom.js

Example request:

```
   function test(){
      $.post("sample_data.php", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
    };
```

On the frontend I get 403 error when the sample_data.php is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure:
First of all create a new route to be called from your js:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="myroute" frontName="myroute">
            <module name="VENDOR_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Than create your controller:
**app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Ajax/GetData.php** - you can call it as you want

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Ajax;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;


/**
 * Class GetData
 *
 * @package Vendor\Module\Controller\Ajax
 */
class GetData extends Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $jsonResultFactory;

    /**
     * GetData constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonFactory $jsonResultFactory,
        Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonResultFactory = $jsonResultFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->jsonResultFactory->create();
        $searchTerm = $this->getRequest()->getParam('some_data'); //if you need data passed from js

        $data = [
            'data1' => 'something',
            'data2' => 'Hello',
            'data3' => 'World'
        ];

        return $result->setData($data);
    }    
}
```

finally jour js file:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/url'
], function ($, url) {
    'use strict';

    var AjaxHelper = function () {};
    AjaxHelper.prototype = {

        /**
         * @param someData string
         * @param setData function
         */
        getData: function (someData, setData) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url.build('myroute/ajax/getdata/'), //myroute is declared in routes.xml, than ajax is the directory and getdata the class 
                data: {
                    some_data: someData
                },
                type: "post",
                error: function () {
                    console.error('Something went wrong');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    setData(data);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    return new AjaxHelper();
});
```

Now you can use your js helper wherever you need  :)

```
define([
    'Vendor_Module/js/ajax-helper',
    'ko'
], function (AjaxHelper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super();
            this.ajaxData = ko.observable();
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @param data
         * @param event
         */
        getData: function(data, event){
            var self = this;
            AjaxHelper.getDada('somedata', function (data) {
                self.ajaxData(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```